# Geolocation com Dados Moveis

Tags: css, angularjs, html5

Bem, estou a tentar fazer um projecto para ser utilizado em SmartPhones, mais em concreto no Android, **mas não esta Desenvolvido em Android !**

*Estou apenas a usar HTML5 e CSS,tudo responsive, e quero por uma funcionalidade que apenas funcionara em Angular(Penso eu)*

**O que Pretendo:**

1. Queria saber como posso fazer com que os Telemóveis através dos **Dados moveis** consigam dar a localização dos mesmos

   2. **ou** ate mesmo que consiga dizer qual dos telemóveis esta fisicamente mais Próximo de um certo local designado (Google Maps ou assim )

> Em relação ao Codigo não pus porque apenas tenho a Front End da
>   Aplicação .... Em relação a localização, a ideia seria mesmo utilizar
>   o GPS do Telemóvel ... Sendo que a pagina Web esta feita apenas para
>   ser utilizada em Telemóvel e não através do Computador ! Para ajudar
>   ainda mais .... Imagine-se que interliga-mos os dois telemóveis em que
>   esta definido um rota e um destino final, e que atraves da Localização
>   de ambos, se consiga dizer qual dos Dispositivos esta mais Próximo do
>   Destino Final !

*Gostava que me pude-sem explicar detalhadamente ou quem não quiser que me possa indicar algum tipo de WebSite/s que me possam ajudar !*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Então, como você não deu detalhes do seu código, vou postar uma explicação em **HTML5** que até pouco tempo lia na documentação da W3C sobre geolocalização.

Há três populares maneiras de obter sua posição:

***Geolocalização IP***
É o método usado pela maioria dos navegadores Web em computadores. Através de consultas whois e serviços de localização de *IP*, vai determinar a cidade ou região em que você está.

***Triangulação GPRS***
Dispositivos conectados a uma rede de celulares e sem um GPS, ou com o GPS desligado, podem determinar sua posição pela *triângulação das antenas GPRS* próximas. É bem mais preciso que o método baseado em IP, vai mostrar em que parte do bairro você está.

***GPS***
É o método mais preciso. Em condições ideais, a margem de erro é de apenas 5 metros.
Embora essas sejam as três maneiras mais populares de se resolver o problema, podem não ser as únicas. Alguns agentes de usuário podem usar uma combinação desses métodos, ou mesmo um novo método que venha a ser inventado. Por isso, a **Geolocation API** é agnóstica em relação ao método usado. Há apenas uma maneira de ligar e desligar o “modo de alta precisão”, o que vai ter significado diferente em cada agente de usuário.

> Vamos a um exemplo:

```
function getPosition() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position, erro);
    }
}

function position(posicao) {
    console.log(posicao.coords.latitude, posicao.coords.longitude);
}

function erro(positionError) {
    console.log(positionError.code);
    if (positionError.code == 1)
        document.getElementById('msg').innerHtml = 'Usuário bloqueou a localização';
}
```

Onde  `postion` é uma função callback, que vai receber um objeto de posicionamento.

O método `getCurrentPosition` recebe dois outros parâmetros. O primeiro é uma função para tratamento de erro o segundo, um objeto de configuração.

Erro vai receber um objeto com detalhes do erro, que será explicado abaixo.

Executando o código acima, o navegador irá exibir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O usuário pode então escolher se deseja ou não compartilhar sua posição com o site. Além de o usuário poder dizer não, muita coisa pode dar errado na hora de obter a geolocalização. Para tratar isso, você pode passar o segundo parâmetro a getCurrentPosition, no nosso caso o callback `erro`.

Caso algo dê errado, a função erro vai receber um objeto `positionError`, que tem o atributo `code`, que pode ter um dos seguintes valores:

**1- Permissão negada**

O usuário clicou em não compartilhar.

**2- Posição indisponível**

O agente de usuário está desconectado, os satélites de GPS não puderam ser alcançados ou algum erro semelhante.

**3- Timeout**

Tempo esgotado ao obter uma posição. Você pode definir o tempo máximo ao chamar getCurrentPosition.

**0- Erro desconhecido**

Alguma outra coisa impediu o agente de usuário de obter uma posição.
Não trate a resposta do usuário como um erro, em sua função de tratamento de erro, se obtiver o código de erro 1, por favor, não incomode o usuário com mensagens de erro. Ele escolheu não compartilhar sua posição com o site. Talvez a melhor atitude seja não fazer nada nesse momento.

**Objeto de configuração**:

O terceiro parâmetro de `getCurrentPosition` é um objeto de configuração, que pode ter as seguintes propriedades:

**enableHighAccuracy**

Se true, liga o modo de alta precisão. Num *celular* isso pode instruir o navegador, por exemplo, a usar o GPS ao invés da triangulação GPRS.

**timeout**

O tempo em milissegundos que o agente do usuário vai esperar pela posição antes de disparar um erro tipo 3.

**maximumAge**
O tempo, em milissegundos, que o navegador pode cachear a posição.

Comment: Ajudou bastante... Muito Obrigado !
Em relação ao Codigo não pus porque apenas tenho a Front End da Aplicação .... Em relação a localização, a ideia seria mesmo utilizar o GPS do Telemóvel ... Sendo que a pagina Web esta feita apenas para ser utilizada em Telemóvel e não através do Computador !
Para ajudar ainda mais .... Imagine-se que interliga-mos os dois telemóveis em que esta definido um rota e um destino final, e que atraves da Localização de ambos, se consiga dizer qual dos Dispositivos esta mais Próximo do Destino Final !

Comment: @ManiacSaw Sim, você pode fazer isso em telefone Móvel também!

Comment: @ManiacSaw, vou editar adicionando o terceiro parâmetro de configuração, que fala de dispositivos moveis.